# Mongoose won't save huge text

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a very big text into my mongodb database but it crash. I'm trying to build a snippet manager and this is my error code:

```
{ [MongoError: Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing beverages.recipes.$code_1 3271 { : "var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sy..." }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing beverages.recipes.$code_1 3271 { : "var gulp = require(\'gulp\');\nvar source = require(\'vinyl-source-stream\');\nvar browserify = require(\'browserify\');\nvar browserSync = require(\'browser-sy..." }',
  driver: true,
  code: 17280,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing beverages.recipes.$code_1 3271 { : "var gulp = require(\'gulp\');\nvar source = require(\'vinyl-source-stream\');\nvar browserify = require(\'browserify\');\nvar browserSync = require(\'browser-sy..." }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

This is my Mongoose Model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let recipeSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true  },
  author: { type: String},
  tags: { type: String, required: true },
  code: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

recipeSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

  var recipe = this;
  // get the current date
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // change the updated_at field to current date
  recipe.updated_at = currentDate;

  // if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
  if (!recipe.created_at){
    recipe.created_at = currentDate;
  }

  next();
});

let Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

export default Recipe;
```

If [found this on mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/), but i don't know how to user it with mongoose. Is it the right thing to do?

This is the document i try to save

```
{ title: 'test',
  tags: 'test',
  code: 'var gulp = require(\'gulp\');\nvar source = require(\'vinyl-source-stream\');\nvar browserify = require(\'browserify\');\nvar browserSync = require(\'browser-sync\');\nvar nodemon = require(\'gulp-nodemon\');\nvar babelify = require(\'babelify\');\nvar eslint = require(\'gulp-eslint\');\nvar buffer = require(\'vinyl-buffer\');\nvar uglify = require(\'gulp-uglify\');\nvar sourcemaps = require(\'gulp-sourcemaps\');\nvar sass = require(\'gulp-ruby-sass\');\nvar config = require(\'./config\');\nvar imageop = require(\'gulp-image-optimization\');\nvar concat = require(\'gulp-concat\');\n\ngulp.task(\'images\', function(cb) {\n  gulp.src(\'./src/assets/images/**/*\')\n    .pipe( imageop({\n      optimizationLevel: 5,\n      progressive: true,\n      interlaced: true\n    }))\n    .pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/images/\'));\n});\n\n\ngulp.task(\'browser-sync\', [\'nodemon\'], function() {\n  browserSync({\n    files: [\'public/**/*.*\'],\n    proxy: "localhost:" + config.APP_PORT,  // local node app address\n    port: 5000,  // use *different* port than above\n    notify: true,\n    browser: "google chrome",\n  });\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'nodemon\', function(cb) {\n  var called = false;\n  return nodemon({\n    script: \'./index.js\',\n    ignore: [\n      \'gulpfile.js\',\n      \'node_modules/\',\n      \'public/,\'\n    ]\n  })\n    .on(\'start\', function () {\n      if (!called) {\n        called = true;\n        cb();\n      }\n    })\n    .on(\'restart\', function () {\n      setTimeout(function () {\n        browserSync.reload({ stream: false });\n      }, 200);\n    });\n});\n\n\ngulp.task(\'browserify\', function () {\n  return browserify({entries: \'./src/client/app.js\', extensions: [\'.js\'], debug: true})\n    .transform(babelify)\n    .bundle()\n    .pipe(source(\'app.min.js\'))\n    .pipe(buffer())\n    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))\n    // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.\n    .pipe(uglify())\n    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(\'./\'))\n    .pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/js\'));\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'lint\', function (cb) {\n  return gulp.src([\'./src/**/*.js\'])\n    .pipe(eslint())\n    .pipe(eslint.format())\n    .pipe(eslint.failOnError());\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'sass\', function () {\n  return sass(\'./src/assets/sass/style.sass\', { sourcemap: true,  style: \'compressed\' })\n    .on(\'error\', sass.logError)\n    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(\'./\', {\n      includeContent: false,\n      sourceRoot: \'source\'\n    }))\n    .pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/css/\'));\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'scripts\', function(){\n  return gulp.src([\'./src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js\',\'./src/assets/js/checkbox.js\',\'./src/assets/js/radio.js\',\'./src/assets/js/bootstrap-switch.js\',\'./src/assets/js/toolbar.js\',\'./src/assets/js/application.js\'])\n    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())\n    .pipe(concat(\'assets.min.js\'))\n    .pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/js/\'))\n    .pipe(uglify())\n    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(\'./\'))\n    .pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/js/\'));\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'fonts\', function() {\n  return gulp.src(\'./src/assets/fonts/**/*\').pipe(gulp.dest(\'./public/fonts/\'));\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'watch\', function() {\n  gulp.watch([\'./src/**/*.js\'], [\'lint\', \'browserify\', \'scripts\', browserSync.reload]);\n  gulp.watch([\'./src/assets/sass/**/*.sass\'], [\'sass\', browserSync.reload]);\n});\n\ngulp.task(\'serve\', [\'browser-sync\', \'watch\']);\n\ngulp.task(\'default\', [\'browserify\', \'nodemon\', \'sass\', \'scripts\', \'fonts\', \'images\', \'watch\']);' }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How big is big? Mongo has a default limit of 16MB per document, so if the size of your text field and the rest of the data in the document is over 16MB Mongo will error out.

Comment: This is what i try to send: http://pastebin.com/GH239n3a with a simple field "title" and another "tags" who had the word "test" in it

Comment: Pastebin is blocked at my work, so I cant see it, but the question remains: **exactly** how big is the text, in bytes?

Comment: This is what i'm trying to pass https://github.com/DWboutin/Beverage/blob/master/gulpfile.js. Not in a file but in text. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use the field `code` as your index. Based on your link the size of the `code` value is ~3KB. Mongo has a limitation that [index fields must not exceed 1KB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#indexes). 3 > 1 therefore you are getting this error.

You can fix this by either:

1. Reducing the size of the text you are entering
2. Not indexing on the `code` field

Comment: oh, but why you use index if you dont need it?

Comment: If there's anyone like me who's wondering why this doesn't work for them: try saving to a new collection in Mongo. That fixed it for me (probably removing the indexes from the old one may have worked as well.)

Answer (score 0):

For index code field use text index. For unique use hash form code.
For example:

```
import crypto  from 'crypto';

let recipeSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true  },
  author: { type: String},
  tags: { type: String, required: true },
  code: { type: String, required: true },
  codeHash: {type: String, unique: true },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

recipeSchema.index({code: 'text'}

recipeSchema.pre('save', function( 

  var recipe = this;
  // get the current date
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // change the updated_at field to current date
  recipe.updated_at = currentDate;

  // if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
  if (!recipe.created_at){
    recipe.created_at = currentDate;
  }

  var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(this.code).digest("hex")
  this.codeHash = hash;
  next();
});
```

Comment: Why should i md5 the code? I just want to store it and display it like it was posted

Comment: I added the document i try to save